# PHP header() function not redirecting when button is clicked on

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement, web

I have 4 forms with a button in each. When the user clicks on the any button, they user gets redirected to differentPage.php

```
<form action="differentPage.php" method="GET">
   <button type="submit" name="food" value="PIZZA">Pizza</button>
</form>

<form action="differentPage.php" method="GET">
   <button type="submit" name="food" value="PASTA">Pasta</button>
</form>

<form action="differentPage.php" method="GET">
   <button type="submit" name="food" value="SANDWICH">Sandwich</button>
</form>

<form action="differentPage.php" method="GET">
   <button type="submit" name="food" value="CHIPS">Chips</button>
</form>
```

On the differentPage.php I have the following code:

```
<?php $foodCode = $_GET['food'];
  if ($foodCode == "PIZZA" || $foodCode == "PASTA" ||
    $foodCode == "SANDWICH" || $foodCode == "CHIPS") {

    header("Location: differentPage.php");

  } else {
    header("Location: thisPage.php");
  }
?>
```

So if I were to modify the value attribute for any of the buttons, it would immediately redirect back to the current page from differentPage.php

However my code doesn't seem to be working. Even though I modify the value so that it doesn't equal PIZZA, PASTA, SANDWICH or CHIPS, it still redirects to differentPage.php

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: aah.. wrong actually. deleted

Answer (score 0):

what are you doing man?

All forms are sent to **differentPage.php** and after entering **differentPage.php**, they are immediately sent to the same **differentPage.php**. This is a vicious circle.

Comment: Yes all forms are sent to differentPage.php and I want it to remain there. However if someone modifies the value attribute and therefore value attribute doesn't equal to PIZZA || PASTA|| SANDWICH || CHIPS, then only do I want it to redirect to the original page